# Orientacion en Azure

Tags: android-studio, azure

tengo una base de datos montada en `azure`, el problema aqui es que utilizo archivos `php` para obtener los valores en `Json` y asi mostrarlos en `Android Studio`, pero la plataforma me cobra por el uso de la aplicacion en Android, mi pregunta es ¿alguien sabe como evitar esto, o alguna otra alternativa?, alguna orientacion de aquellos que ya utilizaron azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Saludos estimado a que te refieres por "orientación"? ¿En Azure tu tendrías tu base de datos, tus servicios REST en PHP, cierto?

Azure te cobraría por ancho de banda, horas de procesamiento y DTU's en la base de datos consumidos por tu aplicación android. Pero no te cobraría por la aplicación android como tal, ya que la app de android corre en los devices.

Si deseas ahorrar recurso puedes adoptar mutliples estrategias:

- Utilizar los planes más económicos en Azure

  - [SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers)
  - [App services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/)

    - Recuerda poner el plan de app service en el tier Free para que no genere gastos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Optimizar ancho de banda no enviando blobs o imagenes en tus archivos json, sino que usar un [cdn o media storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn) para solo enviar las url's de las imagenes

Comment: Creé un App Service, pero me esta cobrando cada que la uso no entiendo porque.

Comment: Claro App Service es un servicio de tipo PAAS en Azure([enlace](http://bugs4fun.com/page/2/)). La única manera que no te cobre es que la cambies al Tier Free, de lo contrario aunque esté detenida seguirá cobrandote.

Comment: ¿como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: 1. Selecciona el Appservice en el portal de Azure 2. Seleccion la opción (Scale Up(App Service Plan) o su equivalente en español) 3. Selecciona el Plan "FREE" que aparece al final del scroll en color amarillo. Modifiqué la respuesta para poner una imagen explicativa.

Comment: excelente ya lo he echo.  dos simples dudas: **¿Con esto ya no me cobrara?** , **¿Que desventajas tengo al utilizar ese plan?**

Comment: Ya no te cobrará, Free es Gratuito. Desventajas, tu sitio no puede pesar más de 1gb, estas usando infraestructura compartida por ende el  procesamiento es más lento, además de esto no podrás asignarle nombres de dominios personalizado(solo puede ser *.azurewebsites.net). [Acá todo el detalle](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/) . Recuerda porfavor marcar las respuesta correcta si he resuelto tus dudas!